# Angularfire login route error

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-routing, angularfire

I have implemented login with Google into my Angular2 app and when I hit login a new window is opened, this is thrown in the console and then the (external) window closes.

I see that it's not able to find a route for `__/auth/iframe` but there is no mention of this in the documentation for angularfire2.

What is the issue here? Do I need to create a new route? If so, which component/module would I point this to?

Here is my `login.component.ts` (I'll exclude the HTML as all it does is call `loginWithGoogle`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {
    private afAuth : AngularFireAuth;
    private db : AngularFireDatabase;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.db = db;
        this.afAuth = afAuth;
    }

    loginWithGoogle() {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }

    logout() {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make sure Google authentication is activated in your Firebase project.